# Como eu passo parâmetro por onclick?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Como eu passo esse parâmetro que está dentro da linha por parâmetro no onclick?

[image: código]

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: Jovem, por favor, poste seu código com texto e não como imagens.

Comment: Leia isso: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5485/132

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente usar algo assim:

```js
editBtn = '<a type="button" onclick="javascript:Devolver('
        + "'XXX'"
        + ')"><span class="btn btn-danger">Devolver</span></a>';
editBtn = editBtn.replace('XXX', row.PlacaDoVeiculo);
return editBtn;
```

Observe que você tinha esquecido também o `>` antes do `<span` que fecha a etiqueta do `<a`.

E da próxima vez, por favor, coloque o código como texto na sua pergunta. Todos neste site odeiam ver código dentro de imagens.

Comment: Vlw Victor, muito obrigado por responder, da proxima vez não uso mais imagens, vi que muitos reprovaram minha pergunta, Obrigado pela dica, vlw !

Comment: @FullStackOverFlow Se essa resposta resolveu o seu problema e não restou nenhuma dúvida, marque-a como correta/aceita ao clicar no "✅" que está ao lado dela, o que também marca a sua pergunta como resolvida. Se ainda te resta alguma dúvida ou gostaria de maiores esclarecimentos, fique a vontade para comentar. :)